# Python - Botão dependendo de caixa

Tags: python, tkinter

Comecei com a desenhar um programa para aprender a programar, no entanto estou com dificuldade em conseguir fazer o seguinte:

1. A pessoa coloca a informação na caixa de texto
2. O Botão vai buscar essa informação e executa uma função.

Conseguem ajudar?

```
from tkinter import *

def Connect():


def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry ("800x600")
    screen.title ("Helpdesk")
    Label (text = "Helpdesk 1.0", bg = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("calibri", 13,)).pack()
    Label (text= "IP Adrress", bg = "white", width = "250", height = "2", font = ("calibri",12,)).pack()
    Box = Entry ().pack()
    Button (text= "Connect", height = "2", width = "30", command = Connect).pack()




    screen.mainloop ()

main_screen ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, você precisa corrigir essa linha:

```
Box = Entry().pack()
```

O problema aqui é que o método `pack()` não retorna nada, então a sua variável `Box` vai ficar vazia (com `None`). Para armazenar o objeto `Entry` em `Box` você precisa dividir isso em duas linhas:

```
Box = Entry()
Box.pack()
```

---

Agora, o seu problema é passar os dados de uma função para outra. Como a função chamada por `Button` não pode ter parâmetros, você precisa usar algum método alternativo para passar o objeto `Entry` para a mesma.

Uma das formas mais simples é usando variáveis globais: Para isso use `global` nas duas funções:

```
def main_screen():
    global Box
    # ... restante da funcao normal ...

def Connect():
    global Box
    ip_digitado = Box.get() # acessa o Entry criado na outra funcao
    print(ip_digitado)
```

Uma outra forma é usar o escopo de uma função para prender a variável (chamado de *closure*). O módulo `functools` tem a função `partial` que serve para isso:

Ao criar o `Button`:

```
Button(..., command=functools.partial(Connect, Box)).pack()
```

Ao chamar usando essa função `partial` é possível passar um parâmetro para `Connect` que seja de escopo local dentro de `main_screen`; Dessa forma não é necessário usar `global`, basta receber o parametro:

```
def Connect(box):
    ip_digitado = box.get()
    print(ip_digitado)
```

A terceira forma, e mais recomendada, é usar classes, e então armazenar os objetos que você vai precisar como atributos de instância:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.screen = root

    def main_screen(self):
        self.screen.geometry("800x600")
        self.screen.title("Helpdesk")
        Label(self.screen, text="Helpdesk 1.0", bg="grey", width="300",
            height="2", font=("calibri", 13,)).pack()
        Label(self.screen, text="IP Adrress", bg="white", width="250",
            height="2", font=("calibri",12,)).pack()
        self.box = Entry(self.screen)
        self.box.pack()
        Button(self.screen, text="Connect", height="2", width="30", 
            command=self.connect).pack()
        self.screen.mainloop()

    def connect(self):
        ip_digitado = self.box.get()
        print(ip_digitado)

screen = Tk()
App(screen).main_screen()
```

Como você pode ver o atributo `self.box` é acessível em qualquer método da classe, tornando-a independente.